# Responsive and centered slideshow with email link

Tags: jquery, html, center, flexslider, responsive

I'm currently trying to improve my very "simple" website.
It's a cycle slideshow that runs automatically is size responsive and perfectly centered. Everything so far works fine.
My only problem is that I would like the slideshow to link to my email when clicking on it. I couldn't make it work other than slapping a big transparent letter on top of it. Does someone else know a better solution to actually implement the link in the slideshow or something?

Thanks for your help. This is my website code it's all I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<title>Photographer</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.slide').cycle({  
    fx:     'none',   
});
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 75vh;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

a {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: transparent;
}

.slide {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.Absolute-Center.is-Resizable {
  max-width: 60%;
  max-height: 85%;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.link {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  height: 85%;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

</style>

</head>

<div class="link">
<a href="mailto:mail@phillip-koll.com">&#65531;</a>
</div>

<ul class="slide">
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_0499.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_1103.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_2070.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_2096.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_2582.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_3335.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_2468.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_2914.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_3098.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_3702.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_3833.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_0238.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well for one you are using <ul> tags in place of <li> tags. That would cause problems for sure

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the slider working and there are a couple of thing to note:

1. Like in my comments use `<ul>` with `<li>` as the child items (see the updated HTML)
2. The images you are using are extremely large in size and the slider downloads all the images on page load so if you dont optimize your images it will be a sucky load time.
3. I removed 2 lines of your CSS, the `position: absolute` takes the images out of their container which messes up your slider (see updated CSS)

HTML

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <a href="<emaillink>"><img src="http://www.phillip-koll.com/files/_MG_0499.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"></a>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  /* THIS IS COMMENTED OUT
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  */
}
```

For the JS your `selector` was wrong so i removed it and your flexslider function was closed prematurely.

JS

```
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,
    keyboard: false
  });
```

[Here is a js.fiddle with it working](https://jsfiddle.net/zp30vken/3/) in case you wanted to play with it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks a ton but I think Flexslider is not the solution then. I will edit the question so we look at my current code, maybe there is something we can do about that. Thank you!

Comment: @PhilK If you update your question make sure to clarify what you mean by "perfectly centered and responsive slideshow".